# WS SOAP null operation

Tags: web-services, soap, null

I'm trying to make a WS but when I open it the following message appears on console:

```
 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] Interceptor for {http://webService.algunDominio.app/}WSLicenciaServService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation: DOMnull (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /BSAnull)
```

The class that contains the WS is:

```
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,
use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,
parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@WebService(name="WSLicenciaServ")



public class WSLicenciaServ {

    @WebMethod(operationName="saludo")
    public String saludo(String name) throws Exception{
        return "saludo "+name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Java? If so, then you should use the [tag:java] tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a web service should implement a service interface your class doesn't suggest that, also you need to specify it as 
`@WebService(endpointInterface="xyz",serviceName="abc")
kindly refer [this](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html)